# How to create cron jobs on Hasura?

Tags: cron, kubernetes, hasura

How can I create, deploy and run and manage [Cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on Hasura?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hasura suggests two ways to deploy and run Cron jobs.

#### Cron microservice

Hasura already has a microservice to run Cron jobs.

If you already have a Hasura project run:

```
hasura microservice create mycron --template=python-cron
```

Change `mycron` to whatever you want to name your microservice. This will create a custom Python microservice designed to run Cron jobs. (Follow further instructions as prompted by `hasura` CLI)

To deploy this on Hasura, git commit and push to your cluster's remote.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Add cron job"
$ git push hasura master
```

To know more about how to customize this microservice, you can read the [docs](https://hasura.io/hub/project/arvishankar/python-cron).

#### Kubernetes Cron jobs

Since, Hasura runs on Kubernetes and Kubernetes (>= v1.8) already provides [Cron Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) as a first class resource, it is recommended to use Kubernetes Cron jobs wherever possible.

If you have `kubectl` installed you can check your Kubernetes version by running: `kubectl version`. In the output, the "server version" shows the version of the Kubernetes cluster. If you are running Kubernetes >= v1.8, we recommend you to use Kubernetes Cron jobs.

When using Kubernetes Cron jobs, you can version control your cron job specs inside your Hasura project, and use the `kubectl` tool to create and manage them.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming Hasura Release 1.3 will support "cron triggers". The beta is already released